# WordPress plugin custom file

Tags: php, wordpress

I used `shiba-example-plugin` as a starting point for my WordPress plugin and I added a filter to redirect after a login so I can do another check before letting the user access the website.

so I redirect with:
`plugins_url() . '/shiba-example-plugin/check.php?id=' . $user_ID;`

How can I structure the 'check.php' file so it would access WordPress variables and have the top admin bar displayed on it?

For now it is just considered a plain php file.

Comment: Tell us what you've tried so far ..

Comment: Maybe an [invisible admin page](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14946783/1287812).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include `wp-blog header` in order to use WordPress global variables.

```
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-blog-header.php');
```